# How can I make the Login Activity start automatically when the authentication fails?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

```
package com.example.madclassproj;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
```

In the Main Activity I get the response either ( 0-FAIL Cannot identify token … ) if the authentication fails or ( 0-OK Hello Leonidas ) if it is successful. I need the another activity (Login Activity) to be automatically started if the authentication is failed.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        TextView textView;
        String server_url = "http://mad.mywork.gr/authenticate.php?t=XYZ";


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

            final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, server_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    textView.setText(response);
                    requestQueue.stop();


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    textView.setText("Something went wrong.");
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    requestQueue.stop();
                                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);



        }


    }
```

Comment: Why don't you start the Login activity when you receive Login failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        TextView textView;
        String server_url = "http://mad.mywork.gr/authenticate.php?t=XYZ";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

            final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, server_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    textView.setText(response);
                    requestQueue.stop();

                    if(!response.equals("0-OK Hello Leonidas")) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    textView.setText("Something went wrong.");
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    requestQueue.stop();
                                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);



        }


    }
```